# How to get all modules from package/subpackage in python

Tags: python

My directory structure:

```
/main
    main.py
    /services
        /package1      
            module1.py
            module2.py
        /package2
            module3.py
            module4.py
        /package3
            module5.py
            /package4
                module6.py
        ...
```

from my `main.py` I want to do something like:

```
modules = getAllModulesFromPackage('services')
modules = getAllModulesFromPackage('services.package3')
```

the `modules` object would be a list with all of the modules from the given package. If I can get the "package object" and pass it as parameter is even better.

how can I do that?

**UPDATE**

This is my real issue, I need to pass to flexApi object a package for it imports all modules of the package

```
flexApi = FlexApi()
flexApi.servicesLocation = 'services'
flexApi.start()
```

why do I need that? because I need to use the modules FROM the flexApi object, like :

```
module1 = flexApi.services.module1()
module1.someFunction()
```

So, the modules need to be "injected" in the `flexApi` object

Comment: Why don't you create `__init__.py` files to: 1. make this an actual package; and 2. define what should be imported from each folder? It's common to define `__all__` as a list of the names to import, which gives you your `modules` list.

Comment: because with the object `modules` I will import all the modules dinamically. So, actually I need to import all the modules from given package, including the modules of the subpackages! that's it

Comment: That doesn't really clarify anything, or explain why you can't use `__init__.py`. Could you give a smaller, less abstract example?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with my real issue, I forgot to say that I'm new with Python (2 days ago I started to use it and became a fan :) ), so may have a simple way to do that, I need to implement this "framework" like that, actually, I'm migrating to python this "framework". If you still didn't understand what I mean, I can edit to put more details